# Refresh Navigation Drawer Fragment Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a question about the navigation drawer fragment. As you know this navigation drawer has multiple sections. Let's say 3 sections (Home, Profile, Log out). My intent is when the user click on Log out, the navigation drawer will refresh itself to (Home, Log in).
I was trying to play with code but I couldn't figured it out..

The files that I have are:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment objFragment = null;

        if(!GlobalVars.is_logged_in)
        {
            //if the user is NOT logged in
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    objFragment = new Home();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    objFragment = new LoginActivity();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if the user is logged in
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    objFragment = new Home();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    objFragment = new Profile();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    objFragment = new Logout();
                    GlobalVars.is_logged_in = false;
                    mNavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(this.getLayoutInflater(), null, null);
                    break;
            }
        }


        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, objFragment).commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        if(!GlobalVars.is_logged_in)
        {
            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mTitle = "Log out";
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        /*if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }*/

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

As you can notice the static variable is_logged_in which is a way to tell me if the user clicked on Log out or not.

I also updated the file **NavigationDrawerFragment.java** that Android studio created for me at the beginning step when it asked me to choose the type of activity and obviously I did not choose a blank one, I chose the Slide menu one that created this Navigation Drawer Fragment

So the code in **NavigationDrawerFragment.java** is

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        if(!GlobalVars.is_logged_in)
        {

            //the user is NOT logged in
            mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new String[]{
                            //section1: home section2: profile section3:login
                            getString(R.string.title_section1),
                            getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    }));
        }
        else
        {
            //the user is logged in
            mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new String[]{
                            //section1: home section2: profile section3:login
                            getString(R.string.title_section1),
                            getString(R.string.title_section2),
                            "Log out",
                    }));
        }


        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        /*if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }*/

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        //actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Any help will be great from you guys...

Comment: I think you need to dive deep into fragment commitments

Comment: The thing here is that I need something very specific.. and as you see I am calling the refreshing method but it seems that it's not refreshing the sections

Comment: Where are you calling refresh method? I suppose you're not meaning `getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` because that works for the Action Bar and not for the Nav Drawer...

Comment: In the MainActivity.java
mNavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(this.getLayoutInflater(), null, null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, Thank you so much guys but I solved this issue by calling the part that is responsible for drawing the side menu bar in the MainAvtivity.java like the following

```
case 2:
                    objFragment = new Logout();
                    GlobalVars.is_logged_in = false;
                    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setupListView();
                    //mNavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(this.getLayoutInflater(), null, null);
                    break;
```

so each time the user click on the Log out it will execute the drawing function

Special thanks to @McAdam331

Answer (score 3):

What I would try is taking the code you use to set the adapter, and putting it into its own method like this:

```
private void setupListView(){
    if(!GlobalVars.is_logged_in)
    {

        //the user is NOT logged in
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        //section1: home section2: profile section3:login
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));
    }
    else
    {
        //the user is logged in
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        //section1: home section2: profile section3:login
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        "Log out",
                }));
    }
}
```

Then, inside onCreateView(), replace all that code with the line `setupListView()`, and then also in the onClickListener for the listview you can check if they clicked logout/logon, and after you change the global variable you can call `setupListView()` again.

Comment: creating the onClickListener should be in the setUp() inside the NavigationDrawerFragment.java, is it right?

Comment: Your onClickListener could stay where it is inside the `onCreateView()` of NavigationDrawerFragment, since that only needs to be set once. It's the adapter setup that may need to happen more than once, which is why I recommend putting it in its own method.

Comment: Are you talking about setOnItemClickListener? inside the onCreateView() method?

Comment: Yes, that's where I would call your update. You could check `if(position ==2){updateListView)` because I believe position 2 is log out.

Comment: It did not work, my problem that it is functionally replace the fragments (the layout that will appear after clicking on the option in the side menu bar). However, still have (Home, Profile, Log out) where profile here doesn't show the profile layout but it shows the Log in layout
the switch is between home, profile, log out, TO home, log in

Comment: I have now something like the following
'code'
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
                if(position == 2){
                    GlobalVars.is_logged_in = false;
                }
            }

Comment: @Riad I believe you'll have to do another check for position. If you have home, profile, log out you're looking for position 2, but if you only have home, log in, you're looking for position 1. That might be the problem.

Comment: I want to switch between them, as I told you the code is already switch between them (functionality only) but it's not redrawing the side menu to have Home and Log in only. It is keeping Home, Profile, Log out

Comment: The problem that I have now is: after switching the functionality if you clicked on Log out then it will break the code and that's because I am still having 3 options instead of 2 my question is why I am not getting 2 options or you can say why it's not refreshing the side menu bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call your item from navigationView object.

```
    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_item_2).setTitle("Hello");
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't help